# MySQL - Update joined column with random values of last 12 digits

Tags: mysql

I have a MYSQL column called Joined (varchar(50)) with values such as 13 numbers
How can I implement that query ?

```
UPDATE `users` SET `joined` = 153ZZZZZZZZZZ
```

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Do you mean Z and X are placeholder for two different numbers repeated multiple times. Or you want 10 random numbers? Also where you get the `153` ? Is a number is a string?

Comment: Edited the question to remove the Z and X confusion and added column type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
UPDATE `users` 
SET `joined` = CONCAT('153', FLOOR(RAND()* 9000000000) + 1000000000)
```

Comment: Same problem as above answer - Some rows have more than 13 digits - Example - `15310758431975` has 14 digits

Comment: @Kal check the edited answer. It should solve digits issue

Answer (score 2):

you could generated md() random string  eg:

```
UPDATE `users` 
SET `joined` = concat('153',SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 10) )
```

or

```
UPDATE `users` 
SET `joined` = concat('153',SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 6), 
                            SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 4) )
```

or if you need only digit you could use

```
UPDATE `users` 
SET `joined` = concat('153',CAST(rand()*1000000 as UNSIGNED), 
                            CAST(rand()*10000 as UNSIGNED) )
```

of for rows with short string  you could use case when for adapt the code as you need

```
UPDATE `users` 
SET `joined` = case when length(joined)= 14 then
                concat('153',CAST(rand()*10000000 as UNSIGNED), 
                            CAST(rand()*10000 as UNSIGNED) )
                    when  length(joined)= 13 then
                concat('153',CAST(rand()*1000000 as UNSIGNED), 
                            CAST(rand()*10000 as UNSIGNED) )
                .....
                end
```

Comment: Thank you - I think I should have mentioned that all characters are numbers like in my example - `1534733449205`.

Comment: oK  .. i think for number only

Comment: @Kal  .. answer  updated ..  hope is what you are looking for

Comment: Yes it is very close but one problem - Many rows do not have the entire 13 digits.  For example I have a row `153691669868`.. So joined date is showing 47 years ago..lol.

Comment: you should check with a case for the lenght of the string  and use different code  ...  ...  anyway the varying lenght  was not in your original question

Comment: thanks. I upvoted your answer. Correct - I do not need varying length. My original question has specific number of Zs and that is what I need.